# Select data from one table based on selected rows in another

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three tables:

books:

```
{id, title, status}
{1, SuperHero, false}
{2, Hobbit, true}
{3, Marvel, true}
```

tags:

```
{id, name}
{1, Drama}
{2, Comedy}
{3, Triller}
```

books_tags:

```
{book_id, tag_id}
{1, 1}
{1, 2}
{2, 2}
```

Every book can have or not many unique for it tags.

1)What is the right way to get all tags with data (tag.id, name) for one book in one query based on book_id?

2)What is the right way to get all books with title by status(true) with array of tags for each book row in one query?

I come up with this for the first one, but struggling with second:

```
SELECT tag_id, name 
FROM books_tags 
    INNER JOIN tags ON tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE book_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second requirement, use the following:

```sql
SELECT
    b.title,
    array_agg(t.name) AS tags
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN books_tags AS bt ON (b.id = bt.book_id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t ON (bt.tag_id = t.id)
WHERE b.status = true
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use the [array type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), which can make your life much easier in this case and make the books_tags table obsolete.

Consider the following setup:

```
create temp table if not exists tags(
    id   int, 
    name text
);
insert into tags(id, name)
values  (1, 'Drama')
       ,(2, 'Comedy')
       ,(3, 'Thriller');

create temp table if not exists books(
    id        int, 
    title     text, 
    status    bool,
    book_tags int[]
);
insert into books(id, title, status, book_tags)
values  (1, 'SuperHero', false, array[1, 2])
       ,(2, 'Hobbit',    true,  array[2])
       ,(3, 'Marvel',    true,  null);
```

Now you can easily execute your queries. e.g. 1)

```
select  book_tags
from    books B 
where   B.id = 1;
```

If you want the tags in separate rows, use the `unnest()` function, e.g.

```
select  unnest(book_tags)
from    books B 
where   B.id = 1;
```

and 2) find all books with `tag in [2]` and `status = true`

```
select  id, title, book_tags
from    books B 
where   B.status = true 
    and B.book_tags @> array[2]  -- set query tags in on right side
```

Your sample data has `status=false` for book 1, so `array[1, 2]` would not bring back any results with that data.  Therefore I've set my example to only use one tag.

Comment: Thanks, but how in this case will search for all books by tag work? Is it fast?

Comment: @RTW I updated the answer.  Keep in mind that your example data has the first book set to `status=false` so that threw me off for a moment there

Comment: but what about performance? I was sure that if you have like 1.000.000 books and in every one is like 5-20 tags it's will be slow to search all books by some tag if you use arrays? I don't even know is there indexes for arrays...

Comment: It's fast because you can index the array column, and you don't need to join on another table which saves a lot of processing power

Comment: In the end my choice is not arrays, this answer make me decide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690430/postgres-many-to-many-vs-multiple-columns-vs-array-column